# Find the volume of the domain situated between $z=\exp(-2(x^2+y^2))$ and $z= 2\exp(-(x^2+y^2+4))-\exp(-8)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Find the volume of the domain situated between the two functions:
>   $$z=e^{-2(x^2+y^2)} \quad\text{and}\quad z= 2e^{-(x^2+y^2+4)}-e^{-8}$$

note: $x>0$ and $y<\sqrt{(4x-x^2)}$

Edit: using cylindrical coordinates I found that: $0<r<4cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 0):

How did you come up with this region in the $xy$-plane? Using cylindrical coordinates, we have
$$z = e^{-2r^2} \quad\text{and}\quad z=2e^{-(r^2+4)}-e^{-8}.$$
These surfaces intersect when
$$e^{-2r^2}-2e^{-(r^2+4)}+e^{-8} = (e^{-r^2})^2 - 2e^{-4}e^{-r^2} + (e^{-4})^2 = (e^{-r^2}-e^{-4})^2 = 0.$$
So the region lies over the region $0\le r\le 2$ in the $xy$-plane.
The volume then is given by
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (e^{-r^2}-e^{-4})^2\,r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Comment: It seems you ignored the inequalities in OP's post

Comment: I asked where those came from. The question was not clearly posed, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

@TedShifrin's answer is partially correct, but we have to take into account the additional domain restriction from the curve $r=4\cos\theta$. The region of integration will be the intersection of the areas of the two circles. This splits the integral into two pieces:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_0^2 \left(e^{-r^2}-e^{-4}\right)^2 \: r \:dr \: d\theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{4\cos\theta} \left(e^{-r^2}-e^{-4}\right)^2 \: r \:dr \: d\theta$$

The first integral is doable but the second does not have an elementary answer. If those inequalities did not come from the problem but instead you (mistakenly) derived them from the expression somehow, the other answer is completely correct.